# How to store DateTime in isolated storage in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I developing an application for Windows Phone. And, here I have a requirement to store DateTime variable in isolated storage.

Is this possible? I know basic types like strings and ints etc can be stored.

Kindly help me thru this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the value as [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in isolated storage and then when you read it just [initialize a new DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instance from it. Ticks is defined as [long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so it should be straight forward to store it.

```
var valueToStore = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
// Save to isolated storage

var storedValue = ReadFromIsolatedStorage();
var dateTime = new DateTime(storedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
DateTime.Parse(string);
```

Convert to string and save in isolated storage. And Retrieve using above statement from storage.

Comment: But after retrieving the string from Isolated storage, not able to convert to DateTimeFormat...

Comment: I have used it a lot of times. Make sure that you are not modifying the datetime after converting to string. Post your code to know where you are getting error.